# What is the functional difference between sudo su and sudo -i?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Why is one preferred over the other in this example?

```
sudo su
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Please provide links to Ubuntu documentation.

Comment: Please reconsider your choice of "accepted" answers. The lowest-voted one is actually the only correct one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `sudo su` command stands for "*switch user*", and allows you to become another user.  It allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified in the `sudoers` file.

The `‑i` (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's `‑c` option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

<sup>Source:[ManPage](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html)</sup>

Comment: "Using su creates security issue, and is essentially dangerous." What?

Comment: That's completely unrelated to using `su`.

Comment: If you run `sudo su` you are asked for your password, not the root password. The root user doesn't even need to have a password. Regardless, if an admin is using the root password, that doesn't imply that all the regular users know it.

Comment: No, it will not. `sudo` runs `su` as root, and root can `su` to any user without knowing their password. Fundamental misunderstandings about how the system works deserve a downvote IMO.

Comment: @OrangeDog  I had some confusion.  I have changed the answer to reflect that.

Comment: And deleting your comments just adds to the confusion.

Comment: I guess that was a mistake. Can you delete yours? :)

Comment: You're not making it much better. `sudo -i` won't ask for root's password either, so it's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 16):

`sudo su` only changes the current user to root. Environment settings (like PATH) remain the same.

`sudo -i` creates a fresh environment as if root had just logged in.

The difference is more noticeable if you use other users. After `sudo su bob` you will be bob, but in the same place. After `sudo -i -u bob` you will be bob, in bob's home directory, with bob's default shell and with bob's `.profile` and any other login scripts having been run.

See [`man sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for more details of what `-i` does. Unfortunately, [`man su`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su) is light on details.

---

Found a version of `man su` (from login-1:4.1.4.2+svn3283-3ubuntu5.1) that has the following to say:

> $PATH reset according to the /etc/login.defs options ENV_PATH or ENV_SUPATH (see below);
>
> $IFS reset to “<space><tab><newline>”, if it was set.
>
> Note that the default behavior for the environment is the following:
>
> The $HOME, $SHELL, $USER, $LOGNAME, $PATH, and $IFS environment variables are reset.
>
> If --login is not used, the environment is copied, except for the variables above.
>
> If --login is used, the $TERM, $COLORTERM, $DISPLAY, and $XAUTHORITY environment variables are copied if they were set.
>
> Other environments might be set by PAM modules.

So whether and to what extent `sudo su` changes the environment depends on your distribution and setup. Thus `sudo -i` is theoretically more portable.

Comment: `su` **does** change environment settings, and can be used to simulate a login using `-` or `-l`. Even without `-l`, `$PATH` **is** changed. Test these claims before making them! (Did you mean that `PWD` remains the same?)

Comment: The real question is, is there a difference between `sudo su -` and `sudo -i`?

Comment: `sudo su` doesn't run `.profile` (it hasn't logged in) or `.bashrc` (it hasn't started bash) or anything, so how would it change PATH?

Comment: Obviously it changes USER and HOME (and SUDO_COMMAND), I guess it must pull from `/etc/passwd`, but I dont' see (and haven't during testing) how PATH can change.

Comment: You're clearly putting some thought into this and actually doing some testing in the shell, so I apologize for my snippy "test these claims" comment. That said, on my system I do observe that `$PATH` is changed when I use `su` without `sudo` (using the root password). According to [`info su`](http://www.fifi.org/cgi-bin/info2www?%28sh-utils%29su+invocation) (which might be a better thing to link to in your answer), `su` does indeed read the password entry for the user you're becoming. Possibly the `$PATH` change I'm observing is system-dependent (I'm on Debian 7).

Comment: Thanks. According to that, `su` changes HOME, USER, LOGNAME and SHELL. `sudo su` changes SUDO_COMMAND and USERNAME (to root) as well. If the shell of the user you're switching to is different to the current shell, it will have to start it, causing its rc file to run.

Comment: Hmmm. My `man su` (which is longer than the one you linked to) says that it's part of `shadow-utils 4.1.5.1`. My `man` page also says that `$PATH` is set even if `--preserve-environment` is used. So I guess it really is just a difference between different versions of `su`.

Comment: The behaviour is also affected by your PAM configuration. `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and `/etc/pam.d/su` may be set up to do completely different or exactly the same things.

Answer (score 10):

The main problem is one of (not so) sane environment settings.

Using `sudo su` the new shell gets its environment from the user who issues the command - which may be problematic.

With `sudo -i` you get a clean root shell.

See [Special notes on sudo and shells](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells)

Remains to observe that it is rarely necessary at all to create a root shell.

Comment: The "special notes" you link to say that `sudo -i` is similar to `sudo su -`, which actually **does not** get its environment from the user issuing the command.

Comment: @KyleStrand thx for pointing this out - it was a typo, the question really is about `sudo su` vs. `sudo -i`.

Comment: Why the `sudo su` would be problematic about the environment? Please can you expand the idea?

Comment: @ManuelJordan please see the "summary" on the page I linked to.

Comment: With what words start that 'summary' section? If you can give me the explicit section's name would be better. Thanks

Comment: @ManuelJordan there is a table named "Summary of the differences found" .