# Why is 'sudo bash' a bad idea?

Tags: bash, sudo, environment

Anyone want to comment on `sudo bash` in comparison to `sudo su` and `sudo -i`?

I know `sudo -i` is the preferred because "environment".

I've gotten into the bad habit from years ago when I was a kid in a basement of using `sudo bash`.

I know it's rather kludgy and awkward, but it works.

I'm looking for a precise and compelling argument to cut my brain free from this habit.

Please tell me why my method is trash? I need an intervention.

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Alright, you got me, not much. I was just here reading something else that got into the whole sudo su vs sudo -i discussion and thought I'd branch that off into another question. Perhaps this explains why it hasn't already been asked here.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used

Comment: Both those other questions talk about how it is different, but not why I should stop using 'sudo bash' so I don't think these present the answer to why 'sudo bash' is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `sudo bash` is wrong, it's just less convenient. For one, it's 2 more characters than `sudo -i`. With `sudo bash` you're just starting `bash` as another user (try doing it and doing `pwd` to see what the current directory is), whereas  `sudo -i` "attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell". `sudo -i` tries to give you an "environment similar to the one a user would receive at login". Also, `sudo -i` will read "login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login". Finally, `sudo -i` will honor the shell the user set in `/etc/passwd`.

On a single-user system these aren't likely to matter too much, but unless you *never* expect to work on a system other than yours, you'd do well to train yourself to do things the recommended way.

`sudo su` is also possibly not entirely wrong (and isn't longer than `sudo -i`), but this option is plainly ugly and looks really kludgy; if you can `sudo`, why `sudo su`, instead of `sudo`ing a proper shell? also, `sudo su` will not properly set the user's login environment, you need `sudo su -` for that, at which point you're again typing 2 more characters than `sudo -i`.