# What is sudo -i

Tags: command-line, server, sudo, root

What does this command? sudo -i?

I'm not sure if I should have made a post with just this question, but since I'm a Linux newbie and I have a lot more questions and doubts, I decided to go ahead and ask. That shouldn't hurt I guess.

And many thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

`sudo -i` starts another bash session as root and uses the directory `/root` as home directory. If you want to enter a root shell, you should almost ever use `sudo -i`

To use your current user's directory as home, use `sudo -s`. **Never start GUI applications from a shell started with `sudo -s`.** The process may transfer the ownership of some important files to the root user, so you can't use them any more!. So use `sudo -i` to enter root shells you want to execute GUI-applications from.

If you just want to execute a program as root, use `sudo program` for command line programs and `gksudo program` for GUI applications.

Comment: I understood you perfectly. I usually just do what you said 'sudo program' and it does the job, but I also like to learn :) Thanks for your time and help ;)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of **`sudo -i`** is well documented in **`man sudo`** (somewhere at the line 137):

> ```
>  -i, --login
>              Run the shell specified by the target user's password data‐
>              base entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific
>              resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the
>              shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell
>              for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is
>              specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts
>              to change to that user's home directory before running the
>              shell.  The command is run with an environment similar to the
>              one a user would receive at log in.  The Command Environment
>              section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option
>              affects the environment in which a command is run when the
>              sudoers policy is in use.
> ```

See also:

- ['sudo su -' vs 'sudo -i' vs 'sudo /bin/bash' - when does it matter which is used, or does it matter at all?](https://askubuntu.com/q/376199/147044)
- [What are the differences between "su", "sudo -s", "sudo -i", "sudo su"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/70534/147044)

Comment: I also don't know what is that command 'man'. So noob :(
I ran it on console and I believe I have an idea how to use it.
Still pretty foggy on what I can do with it. 
Thanks for that information, it helped anyway :)

Comment: @Aryetsok See `man man` :)