# Cannot go into Root

Tags: sudo, root, su

When I enter `sudo su` or `sudo -i` in terminal on Ubuntu 12.04, I cannot become superuser. When I enter the password nothing happens. Its like:

```
user@host~: sudo -i
enter passwd: ******
user@host~: nothing happened
```

And then:

```
user@host~: sudo -s
root@user~: WTF?
```

Instead when my normal user enters `sudo -s` it becomes `root`. Wtf...?

Comment: Are you copy/pasting the full output? Please do so. It should be `root@host` and `:~` instead of `~:`

Comment: And what about `sudo su -`?

Comment: `sudo -s` will look at the environment for a SHELL variable before looking at the users passwd for the chosen shell. `sudo -i` will start at the users passwd. If a SHELL variable is declared that will probably be why. Also I am not sure if the .profile and .login will be read by `sudo -s`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wrong default shell setup for the root user.

- In 1st command `sudo -i`, you passed the login authentication but no shell run.
- In 2nd command `sudo -s`, you are already passed `sudo` authentication which it you are only asked onces per terminal (may be it has a timeout period). However this time, it loads directly `/bin/bash` not shell set in the root profile.

To test this theory run:

```
sudo -i /bin/bash
```

Related: ['sudo su -' vs 'sudo -i' vs 'sudo /bin/bash' - when does it matter which is used, or does it matter at all?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used)