# Bash Tab-autocompletion inside command substitution "$( ... )"

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

I am using Bash's <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocompletion quite often, but when I'm inside a Bash command substitution structure like in the example below, it breaks and only returns an error.

Let's assume I want to find out the file type of the `apt-get` executable, the command for that could be `file $(which apt-get)`. Now if I enter that up to the letter "g" and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I see this:

```
file $(which apt-gbash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Is there any way how I can fix this and use tab autocompletion inside Bash structures like command substitution as well?

Comment: do the tab completion first and then press ctrl+a to go to the start of the line and put in the command to pass arg to and `$(` ? ;)

Comment: @Zanna Yes, that would be a way to avoid the problem, but I prefer a clean fix, if possible :)

Comment: I know, apologies for facetious comment... I am reading up and thinking about how to answer for real, but I'm sure you will figure it out long before me :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/576983/231142

Comment: @Terrance *"Note that none of those solutions will make bash completion inside command substitution work: as mentioned in that same bug report, this is broken in Bash 4.3."* :-(

Comment: Yep.  I tested them out and I get the same result, no completion, but I don't get the error anymore.  :)

Comment: A possibly *slightly* lower effort workaround would be to complete the `which apt-g` and enter it; then use the history expansion `file $(!!)`

Comment: @steeldriver That sounds like a nice idea, but only if the inner command of the command substitution does not modify anything i.e. is purely informative, because it would be executed twice then.

Comment: Does anyone know why typing `type $(which apt-g`, Tab isn't affected by this bug?