# Difference between `sudo su` and `sudo fish`

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, root, fish

I am running fish (Friendly Interactive Shell) as my standard shell in Ubuntu 14.04, rather than bash.

I noticed the following behaviour and don't know, if any of these are the preferred one to gain root access.

I can type the command `sudo su` or `sudo fish` and it will both give me super user rights. (The prompt is displayed as `root@ubuntu ~#`)
Is there any difference in the behaviour of these commands?

The only thing I could understand is, that `sudo su` uses the fish configuration located in `/root/.config/fish/` and `sudo fish` uses the fish configuration in my home directory `/home/uloco/.config/fish`.

Is there a possibility to crypt my system by using `sudo fish`? Will there be any owner changes made to files in my home directory if I use this?

Comment: always remember the old commandment: **thou shalt not claim root's name in vain!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo su` executes `su` as if you were the root user. That means, the shell that is opened is the shell given in the entry of the user in `/etc/passwd` in the 6th field. In case of your systems root user it might be `/bin/fish`. That shell is executed as login shell, so the rc-scripts of the root user are executed.

When you execute `sudo fish`, then the application `fish` (the shell) is executable as if you were the root user, **but** within the environment of the calling user. Thats why fishs rc-scripts are executed.

See a full explanation in this answer: ['sudo su -' vs 'sudo -i' vs 'sudo /bin/bash' - when does it matter which is used, or does it matter at all?](https://askubuntu.com/a/376386/185729)

Which one you should use depends on you:

- Do you want the environment of root as if you login to the system as root? Then call `sudo su`.
- Do you want to preserve your environment, as your aliases and such stuff defined in the shells rc-scritps? Then use `sudo fish`.

> Is there a possibility to crypt my system by using sudo fish?

Its just the environment, you don't crypt something.

> Will there be any owner changes made to files in my home directory if I use this?

Not if you don't change something manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su
```

su - change user ID or become superuser

```
sudo bash
```

bash - GNU Bourne-Again SHell

```
sudo fish
```

fish - is a smart and user-friendly command line
shell for OS X, Linux, and the rest of the family.

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Shell_categories

Bourne-Again shell (bash) and Friendly interactive shell (fish) both are shell types.

Comment: use `su -` or `sudo su -` to go directly to the `$HOME` directory of the user.

Comment: I'm trying to embed a image but I can't edit: Finally :)

Comment: just insert the code :) AUs formatting is not really easy

Comment: @LittleByBlue there was a issue about Imgur or my internet connection :)