# What does ".bashrc or prepend the Anaconda install location" mean?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, root, bashrc

I installed Anaconda from root, after completion of installation this message was displayed on terminal screen:

```
Python 2.7.8 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
creating default environment...
installation finished.
Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda install location to PATH in your /root/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
[no] >>> no

You may wish to edit your .bashrc or prepend the Anaconda install location:

$ export PATH=/usr/bin/anaconda/bin:$PATH

Thank you for installing Anaconda!
root@pkj:~#
```

What does these three following statements mean?

1. Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda install location to PATH in your /root/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
2. You may wish to edit your .bashrc or prepend the Anaconda install location:
3. $ export PATH=/usr/bin/anaconda/bin:$PATH

I accessed root using: `pkj@pkj:~$ sudo su -`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Is asking if you want to add Anaconda to your `PATH`. This basically means that when you type anaconda at the command line interface it knows where to look for it.
2. Just suggesting you do what `1.` recommended or perform the following command so you are able to run anaconda from the command line without first having to go to `/opt/anaconda/anaconda.bin` (this is just an example as i don't know the actual path.)
3. This is a way to add the anaconda install directory to your path so you can just type anaconda. Basically an alternative form of one.
4. Yes i would recommend you execute number three. It won't hurt anything and will likely just make your life easier.

**EDIT**

Also when you are trying to switch to root you can just issue `sudo su` no `-` is needed. Just an fyi it is usually not needed. You might read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used) for details. Either way no biggie

Comment: Thanks @Dylan, I am quite new to Ubuntu and I want two clarifications: 1. Would simply typing `export PATH=/usr/bin/anaconda/bin:$PATH` in terminal do the job? 2. Since I installed it through root, would I be able to access Anaconda from other user accounts?

Comment: Yes issuing that command would have the desired effect and yes you will be able to access it in other user accounts

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Anaconda3, add the following to the very end of your `/root/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

As far as Anaconda path goes, that `export` is all you need to know. Anaconda uses hard links.