# Download Files from Root Directory?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, root, downloads, openvpn

I've looked across this forum, and on the internet and found many people asking what seems like similar questions to myself.  However none of the solutions posed seem to solve my problem.

I haven't got a lot of experience with Ubuntu so please forgive any ignorance, but I've recently got a dedicated server and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I'm using a Windows 10 machine and have access to the server via SSH.

I am attempting to install OpenVPN on the server and I'm following the instructions in this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openvpn.html).  However when I get to the point where it says:

> Copy the following files to the client using a secure method:

```
/etc/openvpn/ca.crt
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/client1.crt
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/client1.key
```

As the client certificates and keys are only required on the client machine, you should remove them from the server.

I get stuck. How do I actually access this `/etc` folder? I normally access files using an FTP client, logging in as a user I created when I first setup the server, but this folder does not appear.  Further the root login details I was emailed don't work when trying to login via FTP.

I would appreciate any help provided in as simple to understand terms as possible. Thanks in advance.

Chappas

Comment: On the Ubuntu computer, you should see `etc` in the root directory.  What do you get when you enter `ls /` on the Ubuntu computer?

Comment: bin   etc         initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt   run   sys  var
boot  home        lib             media       proc  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
dev   initrd.img  lib64           mnt         root  srv   usr  vmlinuz.old

                                                                                                                    I get this. Also please note I don't have local access to the server.

Comment: Ok, `etc` is the second folder you listed in your output.  It doesn't matter that you don't have local access, but having `sudo` access is what will matter.  Are you able to run commands with `sudo`, such as `sudo apt-get install openvpn` in the guide?

Comment: Yes I've created an account which lets me use Sudo called 'Chappas'  however early in the openvpn guide it tells me to change my account to root, so I did this from the by typing 'sudo -i'

Comment: @Chappas  FWIW, typically to switch to root I use `sudo su -`

Comment: Okay thanks FCTW, is there a difference / why are there 2 commands?

Comment: @Chappas  The difference is in how the root shell is launched.  There's a great explanation over at http://askubuntu.com/q/376199/30304

Comment: You can use SFTP instead of FTP. Try "WinSCP" client with the SSH authentication properties. However, in my opinion you can put these files where you want (via FTP) and after that you can `sudo cp` them to the exact place (via SSH). It sounds like the ftp user doesn't have access permission to this folder and the ftp client just doesn't show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you upload the files in question via `sftp` or `scp`.  This has the advantage of being able to use your existing SSH credentials.  There's a great guide on how to do so at http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ftp/connecting-scp-sftp  Once you have the files uploaded, I would `sudo cp` the files to their respective locations, and then adjust the ownership with `chown`, and the permissions with `chmod` to the necessary settings.

Comment: Perfect thank you, this has solved it. I followed the instructions in the link and was able to access the files via FTP with my SSH details. Thanks to all for their advice.

Comment: @Chappas  I'm glad to hear it!  Would you be so kind as to accept the answer?