# How safe is it to use "sudo -i"

Tags: 12.04, sudo

I have few applications which I need to run on `root` permission. Am pretty new to Ubuntu, the kind of shortcut I do to gain `root` access was that I open a new terminal with `sudo -i` and will launch my applications from that terminal. But I need to be cautious while I was in this terminal since I can accidentally mess up something.

Am I doing it right here ? am aware of what `sudo -i` does but my query here is to find any other way that I can achieve this feat or was it only `sudo -i`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What applications are these that you "need to run on root permissions"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the functional difference between sudo su and sudo -i?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331062/what-is-the-functional-difference-between-sudo-su-and-sudo-i)

Comment: I am developing a Qt application to run on a Embedded Linux machine. I have tool chains cross-compiled specific to my target machine where I will be deploying my Qt application. So when I want to run my Qt application on local Ubuntu machine, I would be accessing some resources from `/etc`, `/lib` directories which is not working as expected unless I launch `Qt Creator` application with root permissions. So I basically login with `sudo -i` and launch my `Qt Creator` in that terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Not "safe" at all. Running a command terminal as `root` makes everything you do (including mistakes) **Very Powerful**, and when you try (intentionally or not) to do something dumb, you're not protected by the restrictions placed on non-`root` users.

Programs generally should not require `root` to run (the exceptions are programs that manipulate the system state: mount/unmount disks, install software, shutdown, etc). From the sparse information in your question, it sounds like you have a permissions problem. Figuring out, and solving the permissions problem should be your first step, running as `root` should be the infinitely last step (there must be another way)

Comment: Yep, I sense that problem. I need to figure it out, but basically my requirement is that - my application uses the resources from `/etc` directory which is running fine on my target machine which is by default `root`, but when I run that program on Ubuntu I had a problem.

Comment: Most of the files in `/etc` are readable by non-`root` users. What do you need to read from `/etc`? If your application needs to write to `/etc`, I will assert "Bad Design!"