# When sudo su vs sudo -i

Tags: command-line, sudo, su

I am reading some tutorials about Linux configurations:

- To accomplish many of the configurations is important and mandatory be the `root`.

Well I did realize that in many places are used `sudo su` and `sudo -i`, even when both accomplish the the same goal, I have the doubt about:

- *when is mandatory use one approach over the other?*

I am doing this question because for some reason exists these two approaches

Comment: There is no Central Authority to decide what is *mandatory* and what is not. For most purposes, it does not matter which one you use, so it is a matter of your personal preference. Note that they are not identical: They land you in different working directories and have different environment variables.

Comment: Possibly helpful or possibly even more confusing: https://askubuntu.com/questions/331062/what-is-the-functional-difference-between-sudo-su-and-sudo-i

Comment: There is a [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331062/what-is-the-functional-difference-between-sudo-su-and-sudo-i?noredirect=1&lq=1) about that issue already, that as been answered.
Take a look in there, I think this will answer all your questions!

Comment: @user535733 about `They land you in different working directories` according with the link shared by @chili555 -  which refers to other - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells is not correct. Observe the table values

Comment: @ManuelJordan 'working directory' is different from 'home'.

Comment: Consider to write your answer, if you can add more details would be excellent ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed by the user @user535733 in the comments section, both commands will take you to different working directory.

`sudo su` will execute commands as root in your present working directory but `sudo -i` will take you to your root's home directory (by default to `/root`)

Another difference is if you are using anything other than bash as your shell `sudo -i` and `sudo su` will take you to the shell configured for the root user (`bash` is default in Ubuntu) while `sudo -s` uses the shell you configured for your user(e.g, `zsh`)